# How to shrink large python package for AWS Lambda Layer?

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I'm trying to deploy a python package with large binary dependencies such as `numpy`, `scipy`, `astropy`, `pandas`, etc... The zip file is more than 400MB, so I have to shrink his size below 250MB to be able to deploy it to a lambda layer from S3.

I know I can delete tests, docs and pycache directories with something like

```
find -name "tests" -type d | xargs rm -rf
find -name "docs" -type d | xargs rm -rf
find -name "__pycache__" -type d | xargs rm -rf
```

but this is not sufficient...

Is it theoretically possible to delete *.pyc and *.so files? I know that, for example, the `serverless-framework` with `serverless-python-requirements` offer the `slim` option to package dependencies removing all *.pyc and *.so files. But I think Lambda environment needs these files... I don't want to use any framework if possible and I can run eventually docker to build binaries from a lambda compatible image (I'm working from WSL now). I tried many things but they are not working, I'm not sure why...

I really appreciate any help to understand what it's possible and what it's not to deploy such a huge package to Lambda...

Comment: .pyc files should not be included, .so does need to be there.

Comment: Also, 400MB sounds crazy, even if all those modules were statically compiled

Comment: Ok, thanks. How to not statically compile them?

Comment: For the crazy dimensions thing, I think it's because of transitive dependencies. There is for example matplotlib that I don't use but I think is required by some other package...

Comment: When I hit limitations in lambda, I usually switch to fargate tasks, which can do most of what lambda can do.

Comment: You're also allowed up to 5 layers, presumably you could arrange them in tiers (with each tier depending only on lower tiers).

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround when I've run into this, I did what @jordanm suggested and switched to a Fargate task.

A simpler solution as of December 2020 is to use a [container image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html) for your Lambda.